# How to reshape the window rail from Archimesh

Tags: archimesh-add-on

I am following this tutorial here https://youtu.be/wrzSrjAY69c?t=543 and at this point after adding the rail window it resizes the two main windows into 3 but I just can’t figure out how to do that even if I tried several methods of selecting and moving them.

[image]

This is what I’ve tried so far https://youtu.be/ja3cCsYaFXc

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, didn't get it, that the main problem was making 3 out of 2.

I know BlenderGuru has lots of fans and i am sure i will be very unpopular after that, but i think he tricksed here.

What you can see is, that the third window isn't really realistic:

[image]

[image]

So i am pretty sure that he did cut the video, and he just doubled the window with Shift-D and moved it on the y axis a little bit because else you would have seen these glitches here:

[image]

You can just copy the window in object mode (Shift-D) and move it a bit on the y axis (you have to unlock y axis first), then you have it.

Before he scaled down the windows in edit mode - so you can do that too.

Comment: I don't see how your animation resembles the shared video tutorial. I need to make 3 windows out of those 2. Watch https://youtu.be/wrzSrjAY69c?t=543

Comment: sorry, updated my answer. Didn't understand what you wanted